# ASP MVC Big Gallery Web site Image Storage Best Practices

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, storage, image-gallery

I have a client who wants to build a huge Image gallery website, and I am confused about how to structure the website for future Storage expansion.

Let me explain more...

Let us say that each user will upload his images to

website.com/Uploads/User/Images

Now creating the upload logic and displaying the images is not my issue here, my real problem is that say I have 200 GB hard Disk and if i have 20000 Customer where each client uploads 10 MB max, now as you see I will run out of space.

So how do I handle expansion in future without changing structure of web site, meaning that users will always upload to the same Path I have mentioned above, so obviously my front-end views will fetch images from same location too.

It may be stupid but I am lost on this. I mean, how guys like Facebook or other big sites do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after Tedious Searching, i have found the answer, basically it boils down to two Methods,

One Called Push, where you have to store the Files on the CDN Server by FTP, Api, etc...

The other called Pull Origin, where you dont have to change anything, you just Configure Your CDN to Fetch the Resources from your Servers, of course you have to Store files on Original Server First.

there is a lot more to it, but if anyone had my same wondering , just make Search about CDN Push or Pull in Google

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a cloud cdn(content delivery network), which will be dynamically expandable. amazon/rackspace, they are well known for this kind of service.

Comment: can you explain more please? i mean what about folder structure, i mean will it allow me to keep this same structure i mentioned above ? or i have to change paths?